# How to reduce the recurring code and avoid overwritten the move of player (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, click, innerhtml, overwrite

I've been trying to create a simple project game (Tic Tac Toe) for a couple of days  and finally i did it .....
I wanted to create a simulation between a player and a computer and  I managed to sort things out somehow :)

I faced two problems : 
How can I restrict rewriting of the moves , because i can do this now.
My other problem is : How to avoid repetitive code , like so many repeats " If Statements".

```js
var nextMove = "X".fontsize(8);
    var playerChar = "X".fontsize(8);
    var computerChar = "O".fontsize(8);
    var dataContent = [cell1x1, cell1x2, cell1x3, cell2x1, cell2x2, cell2x3, cell3x1, cell3x2, cell3x3];

    function playerMove () {
        if (nextMove == "X") {
            nextMove = computerMove();
        }
        else {
            nextMove = playerChar;
        }

    }

    function computerMove () {
     
        for(var i = 0; i < dataContent.length; i++){
      
      if (cell1x1.innerHTML === "X" || cell1x1.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
      }
      if(cell1x1.innerHTML === ""){
       
       dataContent[0].innerHTML = computerChar;
       return;
      }
      if (cell1x2.innerHTML === "X" || cell1x2.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
      }
      if(cell1x2.innerHTML === ""){
       
       dataContent[1].innerHTML = computerChar;
       return;
      }
      if (cell1x3.innerHTML === "X" || cell1x3.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
      }
      if(cell1x3.innerHTML === ""){
       
       dataContent[2].innerHTML = computerChar;
       return;
      }
      if (cell2x1.innerHTML === "X" || cell2x1.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
      }
      if(cell2x1.innerHTML === ""){
       
       dataContent[3].innerHTML = computerChar;
       return;
      }
      if (cell2x2.innerHTML === "X" || cell2x2.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
      }
      if(cell2x2.innerHTML === ""){
       
       dataContent[4].innerHTML = computerChar;
       return;
      }
      if (cell2x3.innerHTML === "X" || cell2x3.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
      }
      if(cell2x3.innerHTML === ""){
       
       dataContent[5].innerHTML = computerChar;
       return;
      }
      if (cell3x1.innerHTML === "X" || cell3x1.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
      }
      if(cell3x1.innerHTML === ""){
       
       dataContent[6].innerHTML = computerChar;
       return;
      }
      if (cell3x2.innerHTML === "X" || cell3x2.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
      }
      if(cell3x2.innerHTML === ""){
       
       dataContent[7].innerHTML = computerChar;
       return;
      }
      
      if (cell3x3.innerHTML === "X" || cell3x3.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
      }
      if(cell3x3.innerHTML === ""){
       
       dataContent[8].innerHTML = computerChar;
       return;
      }
      
      
      
      
     }
    }

    $("#cell1x1").click(function(){
     if (cell1x1.innerHTML === "X" || cell1x1.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
        }
      cell1x1.innerHTML = "X";
      cell1x1.innerHTML = nextMove;
      playerMove();
      computerMove();
     
    });

    $("#cell1x2").click(function(){
     if (cell1x2.innerHTML === "X" || cell1x2.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
     }
      cell1x2.innerHTML = "X";
      cell1x2.innerHTML = nextMove;
      playerMove();
      computerMove();
      
    });

    $("#cell1x3").click(function(){
     if (cell1x3.innerHTML === "X" || cell1x3.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
        }
      cell1x3.innerHTML = "X";
      cell1x3.innerHTML = nextMove;
      playerMove();
      computerMove();
    });

    $("#cell2x1").click(function(){
     if (cell2x1.innerHTML === "X" || cell2x1.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
        }
      cell2x1.innerHTML = "X";
      cell2x1.innerHTML = nextMove;
      playerMove();
      computerMove();
    });
    $("#cell2x2").click(function(){
     if (cell2x2.innerHTML === "X" || cell2x2.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
        }
      cell2x2.innerHTML = "X";
      cell2x2.innerHTML = nextMove;
      playerMove();
      computerMove();
    });
    $("#cell2x3").click(function(){
     if (cell2x3.innerHTML === "X" || cell2x3.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
        }
      cell2x3.innerHTML = "X";
      cell2x3.innerHTML = nextMove;
      playerMove();
      computerMove();
    });
    $("#cell3x1").click(function(){
     if (cell3x1.innerHTML === "X" || cell3x1.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
        }
      cell3x1.innerHTML = "X";
      cell3x1.innerHTML = nextMove;
      playerMove();
      computerMove();
    });
    $("#cell3x2").click(function(){
     if (cell3x2.innerHTML === "X" || cell3x2.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
        }
      cell3x2.innerHTML = "X";
      cell3x2.innerHTML = nextMove;
      playerMove();
      computerMove();
    });
    $("#cell3x3").click(function(){
     if (cell3x3.innerHTML === "X" || cell3x3.innerHTML === "O") {
            return;
        }
      cell3x3.innerHTML = "X";
      cell3x3.innerHTML = nextMove;
      playerMove();
      computerMove();
    });
```

```css
.data1x1 ,.data1x2 ,.data1x3,.data2x1 ,.data2x2 ,.data2x3 ,.data3x1 ,.data3x2 ,.data3x3{
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
        border-right:1px;
     border-style: solid;
    }

    .tableContent{
        background-color: white;
        margin: 150px auto auto;
    }

    .body{
        background-color: lightskyblue;

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tic tac toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCss.css">
    </head>

    <body class="body">
    <div class="container">
     <table class="tableContent">
            <tr class="rowContent">
       <td id="cell1x1" class="data1x1"></td>
       <td id="cell1x2" class="data1x2"></td>
       <td id="cell1x3" class="data1x3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowContent">
       <td id="cell2x1" class="data2x1"></td>
       <td id="cell2x2" class="data2x2"></td>
       <td id="cell2x3" class="data2x3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rowContent">
       <td id="cell3x1" class="data3x1"></td>
       <td id="cell3x2" class="data3x2"></td>
       <td id="cell3x3" class="data3x3"></td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myScript.js" ></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: It's probably better to ask this question over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several things that can be improved, which of course will happen as more experience is acquired. I'll cover the two items that you specifically asked about, and a little more.

First, the "move rewrites":
When each click is tested for the X and O, the actual content being compared looks like this:

[image]

Which obviously does not match a single X or O.

So, based on that, I would **NOT** have expected the font to be set in this manner:

```
var nextMove = "X".fontsize(8);
```

...but rather, I would have expected that the font size would be set in CSS with the dataXxY properties using `font-size` instead:

```
.data1x1 ,.data1x2 ,.data1x3,.data2x1 ,.data2x2 ,.data2x3 ,.data3x1 ,.data3x2 ,.data3x3 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-right:1px;
    border-style: solid;
    font-size: 48px; /* adjust as needed */
}
```

I removed the `.fontsize(8)` from these other two variables to be simple strings, so that we only work with X and O:

```
var playerChar = "X";
var computerChar = "O";
```

While we're on CSS, unless there will be some future need to have individual .data* CSS names, can all those names for the data style be reduced to one name?  For example:

Replace all these:

```
.data1x1 ,.data1x2 ,.data1x3,.data2x1 ,.data2x2 ,.data2x3 ,.data3x1 ,.data3x2 ,.data3x3
```

... with something like this: (feel free to rename to your liking)

```
.dataCell
```

... and then change the same for all the ones within the html file too.

=====

Reducing conditions:

One way could be to have a function where you can pass a cell to check, but the function's handling can then check the element's string content. (if this makes sense?)

For example, the function could look like this:
(feel free to rename to your liking)

```
function occupiedCell( elementRef ) {
    return( elementRef.innerHTML === playerChar || elementRef.innerHTML === computerChar );
}
```

... which then reduces the computerMove() code/handling to use the loop on the `dataContent` array as naturally expected, like this:

```
function computerMove () {
    
    for(var i = 0; i < dataContent.length; i++){
        
        if ( !occupiedCell( dataContent[i] ) ) {
            dataContent[i].innerHTML = computerChar;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

=====

However, some additional items are needed to support the computerMove() changes:

The playerMove() function does **NOT** appear to be necessary. Each click handler already ***sets*** "X" for the player. There is a variable named nextMove which is set to X. This variable is no longer needed because it's used inside the playerMove function. (it will be removed from the click handlers too, as noted below)

Each click handler's code can now be reduced to this:

```
if (cell1x1.innerHTML === "X" || cell1x1.innerHTML === "O") {
    return;
}
cell1x1.innerHTML = playerChar;
//      cell1x1.innerHTML = nextMove;
//      playerMove();
computerMove();
```

... but abstracting that handling code a bit more, create another function to use from each click handler, which will also make use of the new occupiedCell() function created earlier:

```
function setPlayerX( elementRef ) {
    if ( !occupiedCell( elementRef ) ) {
        elementRef.innerHTML = playerChar;
        computerMove();
    }
}
```

... then that function is used by each click handler like this small example for the first three handlers:

```
$("#cell1x1").click(function(){
    setPlayerX( dataContent[0] );
});

$("#cell1x2").click(function(){
    setPlayerX( dataContent[1] );
});

$("#cell1x3").click(function(){
    setPlayerX( dataContent[2] );
});

// Apply the similar change to the other 6 click handlers.
// Ensure to set the correct dataContent array index within each handler!
```

I'll stop here for now, as I'm sure that is enough to review and/or ponder.
Feel free to ask questions, if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to look at my code and to give me these good ideas that will really reduce the code. I'll take a time to review all my code and try to change it. In other hand i'll think how to use random moves for computer , бut so far there are other things to think about :)